# Construct stringstream from char

Tags: c++, string, char, digits

I implemented the following code, which does what it's supposed to, but I think that it can / should be simplified.

Basically, I need to create a vector of numbers, each containing one of the digits found in testString. Is there any way to construct the stringstream directly from a char (i. e. testString[i])? I'd rather not involve C-style functions, like atoi, if it can be done in a C++ way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::string testString = "abc123.bla";
    std::string prefix = "abc";

    std::vector<unsigned short> digits;

    if (0 == testString.find(prefix))
    {
        for (size_t i = prefix.size(); i < testString.find("."); ++i)
        {
            int digit;
            std::stringstream digitStream;
            digitStream << testString[i];
            digitStream >> digit;
            digits.emplace_back(digit);
        }
    }

    for (std::vector<unsigned short>::iterator digit = digits.begin(); digit < digits.end(); ++digit)
    {
        std::cout << *digit << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could make use of the string constructor that takes a character and the number of that character to construct it out of (e.g. `(3, 'a') == aaa`).

Comment: `testString[i] - '0'` if I understand correctly.

Comment: @oldrinb testString[i] will evaluate to '1', '2', '3' during the iterations.

Comment: `std::stringstream tempstream() {return {};}`

Comment: @MihaiTodor `'1' - '0'` evaluates to `1`, `'2' - '0'` to `2`, etc.

Comment: Careful, it only works portably for numbers, not letters.

Comment: @chris Are you referring to ASCII vs UTF8 issues?

Comment: @MihaiTodor, ASCII isn't guaranteed to be in use. Just look at something like EBCDIC's table of character codes.

Comment: @chris Yeah, well, let's hope that I won't need to open that can of worms :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `testString[i]` is between `'0'` and `'9'`, just do:

```
digits.emplace_back(testString[i] - '0');
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh... Good idea! Why didn't I see that? Thanks! :)

Comment: @jrok, There's no match for that string constructor. Technically you could then try something like `std::string num(123);` and it would construct it with whatever character is 123 instead of a length of 123 or a string representation of 123.

Comment: @chris You're right, thanks. I just assumed it would be, I never had to actually construct 1 char string before :) This one works: `std::istringstream digitStream(std::string(1, testString[i]));`

Comment: @jork: Yes, I managed to do that also, but your solution is much more elegant. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

See [my original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376584/construct-stringstream-from-char#comment16625032_12376584); subtract `'0'` from each digit character.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

...

std::string input = "abc123.bla";
std::string prefix = "abc";
std::vector<unsigned short> digits;

auto input_b = input.begin();
std::copy_if(input_b, std::find(input_b, input.end(), '.'),
    std::back_inserter(digits), (int (*)(int)) std::isdigit);

auto digits_b = digits.begin();
auto digits_e = digits.end();
std::transform(digits_b, digits_e, digits_b,
    std::bind2nd(std::minus<unsigned short>(), '0'));
std::copy(digits_b, digits_e,
    std::ostream_iterator<unsigned short>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

It can even be shortened if you don't need `digits` to contain the intermediate digit values.

```
std::transform(digits.begin(), digits.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<unsigned short>(std::cout, "\n"),
    std::bind2nd(std::minus<unsigned short>(), '0'));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide such an elaborate approach, but I'm afraid that my knowledge of the STL is not sufficient to comprehend what's happening there. I will look into `std::copy_if`, `std::back_inserter`, `std::transform`, `std::bind2nd` and `std::minus`, since I've never used them before.